# How to get an object from an array on button click in vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a table and in the table I am looping through an array of objects.

```
    <table class="table table-striped" v-if="bins.length > 0">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Location</th>
            <th scope="col" class="text-end">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(bin, index) in bins" :key="index">
            <th scope="row">{{index + 1}}</th>
            <td ref="txtLocaton" contenteditable="false" v-text="bin.binlocation"></td>
            <td class="text-end">
            <div class="action-btn">
                <button @click="btnEdit"><fa icon="edit" /> Edit</button>
                <button><fa icon="trash" /> Delete</button>
            </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

What I would like is that on the `Edit` button click, I want to change the `contenteditable` attribute from false to true.

This is the code for the data()

```
<script>
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            bins:[
                {
                    binlocation: '11 Garden Block, New City',
                },
                {
                    binlocation: 'Ali Towers, Lahore'
                },
                {
                    binlocation: 'The Mall Road'
                }
            ]
        }
    },

    methods:{
        btnEdit(){
          console.log(this.$refs.txtLocaton)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I am thinking about changing the attribute using `ref` but when I console it, it is returning the last array on button click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may store `contenteditable` keys in `bins` array (`false` initially?):

```js
[{
  binlocation: '11 Garden Block, New City',
  contenteditable: false,
}, {
  binlocation: 'Ali Towers, Lahore',
  contenteditable: false,
}, ...]
```

Then bind `contenteditable` `td` attribute to those values (instead of passing `false` directly):

```html
<td ref="txtLocaton" :contenteditable="bin.contenteditable" v-text="bin.binlocation"></td>
```

And simply toggle values as you wish when 'edit' button pressed:

```html
<button @click="bin.contenteditable = !bin.contenteditable"><fa icon="edit" /> Edit</button>
```

or

```html
<button @click="btnEdit(index)"><fa icon="edit" /> Edit</button>
```

```js
btnEdit(index) {
  this.bins[index] = !this.bins[index]; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. BTW I am also trying to make this text focus when the user clicks on the button. Please help me out with that also. I am trying this using refs like so
this.$refs.txtLocaton.focus();
but I am not sure how to pass the index

Comment: @MuhammadAmeenSheikh let me clarify, you need to focus `td`/`tr` when user clicked on 'Edit' button, right? It might happen 'cause neither `td` or `tr` DOM elements is "focusable". You can check docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus).

Comment: @MuhammadAmeenSheikh maybe solution you are looking for is add own styles to new class (to simulate focus) and toggle this class on target elements like with `contenteditable` attribute. I mean something like: `<td ref="txtLocaton" :contenteditable="bin.contenteditable" v-text="bin.binlocation" v-class="{ focusClass: 
bin.contenteditable }"></td>` where `focusClass` - your implementation.

Comment: I am trying to add the class to it like you suggested.
  this.$refs.locTxt.classList.add('focusable')
The class gets added but it is added to the last element in the array. I now know that I have to pass the index but I am not sure how to pass it using $refs

Comment: @MuhammadAmeenSheikh I'm not sure you need to use `$refs`. You can access DOM element you interacted with, using `$event`, this way is simpler. Please, check `$event` docs [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers).

Answer (score 1):

Try like following snippet (You can pass index to your method and bind contenteditable attribute to data property):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data(){
    return{
      bins:[
        {binlocation: '11 Garden Block, New City',},
        {binlocation: 'Ali Towers, Lahore'},
        {binlocation: 'The Mall Road'}
      ],
      editable: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
    btnEdit(index){
      this.editable = index
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```css
.editable {
  border: 2px solid violet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <table class="table table-striped" v-if="bins.length > 0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Location</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-end">Action</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(bin, index) in bins" :key="index">
        <th scope="row">{{index + 1}}</th>
        <td ref="txtLocaton" :contenteditable="index === editable" :class="index === editable && 'editable'" v-text="bin.binlocation"></td>
        <td class="text-end">
        <div class="action-btn">
          <button @click="btnEdit(index)"> Edit</button>
          <button> Delete</button>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```